# Syntax highlighting text/ng-template Intellij

Tags: angularjs, scala, intellij-idea, ng-template

Intellij (v2017.3) doesn't recognize the tag `<script "text/ng-template">` as an Angularjs template fragment.

Maybe it's because I'm in a scala view ?

I tried to add a custom language injection as described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207004385/comments/207299999) but it doesn't work...

My angularjs plugin is correctly enabled... I don't know where to look.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Looks like: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7308

Comment: 16 Jul 2014... :(
Do you know a way to fix it ?